# Is there a facility in boost to allow for write-biased locking?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

If I have the following code:

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

boost::shared_mutex g_sharedMutex;

void reader()
{
    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(g_sharedMutex);
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));
}

void makeReaders()
{
    while (1)
    {
        boost::thread ar(reader);
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(3));
    }
}

boost::thread mr(makeReaders);
boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(g_sharedMutex);

...
```

the unique lock will never be acquired, because there are always going to be readers. I want a unique_lock that, when it starts waiting, prevents any new read locks from gaining access to the mutex (called a write-biased or write-preferred lock, based on my wiki searching).  Is there a simple way to do this with boost? Or would I need to write my own?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the write lock is never acquired? If so how and on what OS? I'm looking at the pthread implementation and it should prioritize write locks. I'm not entirely sure what the win32 implementation is doing though.

Comment: I didn't actually verify for this case - I did verify that new read locks ARE acquired though after a write lock is requested, which seems like a recipe for deadlock. I'm looking for a guarantee that, assuming all read locks will eventually be released, write lock will be quickly obtained, and not delayed due to new read locks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that I won't comment on the win32 implementation because it's way more involved and I don't have the time to go through it in detail. That being said, it's interface is the same as the pthread implementation which means that the following answer should be equally valid.

The relevant pieces of the pthread implementation of boost::shared_mutex as of v1.51.0:

```
void lock_shared()
{
    boost::this_thread::disable_interruption do_not_disturb;
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lk(state_change);

    while(state.exclusive || state.exclusive_waiting_blocked)
    {
        shared_cond.wait(lk);
    }
    ++state.shared_count;
}

void lock()
{
    boost::this_thread::disable_interruption do_not_disturb;
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lk(state_change);

    while(state.shared_count || state.exclusive)
    {
        state.exclusive_waiting_blocked=true;
        exclusive_cond.wait(lk);
    }
    state.exclusive=true;
}
```

The while loop conditions are the most relevant part for you. For the lock_shared function (read lock), notice how the while loop will not terminate as long as there's a thread trying to acquire (`state.exclusive_waiting_blocked`) or already owns (`state.exclusive`) the lock. This essentially means that write locks have priority over read locks.

For the lock function (write lock), the while loop will not terminate as long as there's at least one thread that currently owns the read lock (`state.shared_count`) or another thread owns the write lock (`state.exclusive`). This essentially gives you the usual mutual exclusion guarantees.

As for deadlocks, well the read lock will always return as long as the write locks are guaranteed to be unlocked once they are acquired. As for the write lock, it's guaranteed to return as long as the read locks and the write locks are always guaranteed to be unlocked once acquired.

In case you're wondering, the `state_change` mutex is used to ensure that there's no concurrent calls to either of these functions. I'm not going to go through the unlock functions because they're a bit more involved. Feel free to look them over yourself, you have the source after all (`boost/thread/pthread/shared_mutex.hpp`) :)

All in all, this is pretty much a text book implementation and they've been extensively tested in a wide range of scenarios (`libs/thread/test/test_shared_mutex.cpp` and massive use across the industry). I wouldn't worry too much as long you use them idiomatically (no recursive locking and always lock using the RAII helpers). If you still don't trust the implementation, then you could write a randomized test that simulates whatever test case you're worried about and let it run overnight on hundreds of thread. That's usually a good way to tease out deadlocks.

Now why would you see that a read lock is acquired after a write lock is requested? Difficult to say without seeing the diagnostic code that you're using. Chances are that the read lock is acquired after your print statement (or whatever you're using) is completed and before state_change lock is acquired in the write thread.

Comment: Just an irrelevant pedantic note. The read lock is actually not guaranteed to always return. If there's a none stop stream of threads trying to acquire the write lock, then the read lock will never return because write locks are always prioritized over read locks. If you're running into this problem then a generic shared_lock implementation probably isn't going to cut it. Oh and you also have much bigger problems to worry about :)

Comment: So you are saying unique_lock IS write biased like the above `lock()` method? Updating code with output - I am pretty sure I am getting to the unique_lock before the applicable shared_lock. Also in your above example, it's write-biased for the first writer, but looks like a 2nd writer will be racing a read thread for the state_change lock, and may beat out the writer in that case.

Comment: Okay I sanity checked my test a bit...in my actual test in main thread I create a read thread that executes `wait(2); shared_lock(gLock);`, while the main thread immediately goes for the unique_lock after creating this thread. I assumed that the main thread would execute within those 2 seconds, but I was apparently mistaken! I actually wrote my own lock very similar to what you have above, which will suffice until I can convince my team to adopt boost...

Comment: @Rollie You're right that a second write lock will compete with at most one read lock. This can be easily adjusted by replacing the `exclusive_waiting_blocked` bool by a write waiting counter like `shared_count`.